# Pasar una variable a una vista con laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

Buenas noches estoy usando laravel 5.6, y tengo una duda deseo pasar una variable a mi vista con la finalidad de poder usarla y me ayude a definir el insertar o no un formulario a la vista en el controlador tengo el siguiente código:

```
public function listar($dato=""){
               if ($dato="pendiente") {
        $LlamadaDetectar=true;
        $asignacion=DB::table('asignacions')
        ->join('rangos','funcionarios.id_rango','=','rangos.id_rango')
        ->join('almacens','asignacions.id_almacen','=','almacens.id_almacen')
        ->select('id_asignacion','rangos.abreviacion AS grado','almacens.descripcion AS Oficina','asignacions.estado AS estadoAsignacion')
        ->where('asignacions.estado','=', 1)
        ->where('almacens.almacen_padre','=', $almaceUsuario)->paginate(25);
    }
    elseif($dato=""){
        $LlamadaDetectar=false;
        $asignacion=DB::table('asignacions')
        ->join('rangos','funcionarios.id_rango','=','rangos.id_rango')
        ->join('almacens','asignacions.id_almacen','=','almacens.id_almacen')
        ->select('id_asignacion','rangos.abreviacion AS grado','almacens.descripcion AS Oficina','asignacions.estado AS estadoAsignacion')
        ->where('almacens.almacen_padre','=', $almaceUsuario)->paginate(25);
    }
   }
    return view('material.asignaciones',compact('asignacion'))->with('LlamadaDetectar', $LlamadaDetectar);

}
```

La variable que estoy enviando es *$LlamadaDetectar=true;*

La cual trato de usarla en mi vista de la siguiente forma:

```
<h2 class="text-center">Asignaciones de material</h2>
<div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3 col-md-12">
 <div class="input-group">
   <?php
   if ($LlamadaDetectar=false) {
     echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='buscarAsignacion'>"; 
   }
   ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: te marca algún error? de ser así que error te marca?

Comment: No me marca error Alfredo Paz pase la variable por dd y se la ve con el valor que se le asigna en el controlador, el problema esta en la vista que no la reconoce

Comment: te adjunte una respuesta @ALVARO ROBERTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a trabajar con la sintáxis de blade en las vistas de Laravel; que de hecho es lo recomendado, entonces tu código debería lucir así

```
@if($LlamadaDetectar == false)
    {!! "<input type='text'>" !!}
@endif
```

Con lo anterior te evitas de estar insertando código backend en php puro, lo cual mantendrá mas órden el archivo de vista; además de beneficiarte de blade

Por otro lado te comento que tu if es incorrecto desde el momento en que tratas de verificar si una variable es false o true; ya que estas usando solo un operador de igual, la cosa va así

1. = Significa igualación a = 9; estamos diciendo que a es igual a 9
2. == Significa comparación 10 == 10, retornará true por que 10 si es igual a 10

Comment: Tienes mucha razon Alfredo Paz, corregi tal cual me indicaste y funciono  a la perfección, nuevamente muchas gracias siempre tu aclarando mis dudas